# Canvas width in CSS looks bad and doesn't agree with javascript code

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm working on a small webpage that generates a figure based on user input. I plan to place a `canvas` in the `html` code, and to use `javascript` to create the image. The problem I have is that the `canvas` size as defined in the `css` file seems to only scale a small `canvas` and not to actually create a bigger one. This is my `html` code

```js
function test() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    if (null == canvas || !canvas.getContext) return;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    for (var i = 0; i <= canvas.width; i += 50) {
        for (var j = 0; j < canvas.height; j += 20) {
            ctx.fillText(j, i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgba(0, 100, 100, 0.2);
    width: 100%;
}
    
canvas {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>
      Test
   </title>

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
        maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/worker.js">
   </script>

</head>

<body onload="test()">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

The output, looks like this (The same happens when I replace the `width` of the `canvas` in the `css`file to `100%`)

[image]

why wouldn't I get smaller numbers that go up to 700?

Comment: Set the canvas width in javascript, not in css.

Answer (score 3):

Your mystery width and height are coming from the canvas default values in the absence of `width` and `height` attributes.  These default values are 300 for width and 150 for height. Read more on the [HTMLCanvasElemnet here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement#Properties).

To correct this behaviour, you can either give it a static width and height using those attributes (not ideal), or you can set the width and height with javascript.  I suggest using `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` properties.  It will also be necessary to set these values whenever the window resizes.  That can be done with an event listener.  Here's a demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/f7btghdr/2/

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

function test() {
  for (var i=0; i <= canvas.offsetWidth; i += 50){
    for (var j=0; j <= canvas.offsetHeight; j += 20){
      ctx.fillText(i + 'x' + j,i,j);
    }
  }
}

function adjustCanvas() {
  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.textBaseline="top";
  test();
}

window.addEventListener('resize', adjustCanvas);
adjustCanvas();
```

```css
html, body, canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

## Edit

Per Kaiido's comments below, the following snippet is probably a better approach to this.  Of note, the `clearRect` call was superfluous, `getBoundingClientRect` should give more precise values for the width and height of the canvas, and the canvas CSS is also unnecessary (it gets overridden with the `width` and `height` properties right away anyway).  Below is a revised demo with these changes in place.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

function test() {
  for (var i=0; i <= canvas.offsetWidth; i += 50){
    for (var j=0; j <= canvas.offsetHeight; j += 20){
      ctx.fillText(i + 'x' + j,i,j);
    }
  }
}

function adjustCanvas() {
  var dimensions = canvas.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
  canvas.width = dimensions.width;
  canvas.height = dimensions.height;
  ctx.textBaseline="top";
  test();
}

window.addEventListener('resize', adjustCanvas);
adjustCanvas();
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

.canvas-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-wrapper">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to `clearRect` after setting the `width`or `height` properties since it will reset the canvas' context. Btw, that's why you needed to set again `textBaseline` in the `adjustCanvas`. Also, keep in mind that `offsetXXX` does return integers, so in case you size your canvas in relative values (%), CSS antialising will again kicks in and destroy your drawings. `getBoundingClientRect()` is more precise so it could avoid it, but IMM the best is just to get the size of the container and not set CSS at all on canvas.

Comment: Also, `offsetXXX` will get the border box, so one may prefer `clientXXX` properties, which also round up values...

Comment: @Kaiido Wow! Thanks for all the insight.  I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to set the canvas width and height using `window.innerWidth` & `window.innerHeight`.
This will match the viewport of the device.

```
function test() {
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
   canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
   if (null == canvas || !canvas.getContext) return;

   ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

   for (var i = 0; i <= canvas.width; i += 50) {
      for (var j = 0; j < canvas.height; j += 20) {
         ctx.fillText(j, i, j);
      }
   }
}
```